# Get photo where user is tag in with Facebook graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

with this bloc of code, I get all the albums of a user, but I don't have the photo where the user is "tag". How I can get this pictures like any other album of the user.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"user_photos", nil] defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status,NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         NSLog(@"error");

         return;
     }
     else
     {
         [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
         NSLog(@"LOGIN SUCCESS");

         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/albums?fields=id,name,count"
                                      parameters:nil
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                               completionHandler:^(
                                                   FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
          {
              NSLog(@"%@",result);

              self.arrayAlbumDetails = result[@"data"];

              if (self.arrayAlbumDetails.count == 0)
              {
                  NSLog(@"Either the user does not have any albums or something bad happen.");
              }
              else
              {
                  [self.tblFacebookAlbumList reloadData];
              }
          }];

     }
 }];
```

Thanks